# Is there a tool that beeps and highlights matching lines that are piped through it, while displaying everything

Tags: command-line, bash, shell

Is there a tool that will let me pipe the output of an executable through it and play a sound or, better yet, highlight the line where a selected phrase occurs?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
./myProgWithLotsOfOutput  | ./myMysteryTool blahUsefulWord
```

and have all of the output appear and scroll by, but any time "blahUsefulWord" appears, the console beeps and highlights that line.

It's kind of a mix of [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) and [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep). Alternatively, do you have the BASH skills to whip something like this up?

Answer (score 2):

For Bash >= version 3.2:

```
regex='some regex pattern'
highlight=$(tput setaf 2) # green, use setab to do inverse instead of foreground
off=$(tput sgr0)
while read line
do
    [[ $line =~ $regex ]] && echo -n $'\07'"$highlight"
    echo "$line$off"
done
```

It highlights the whole line rather than just the match.

Answer (score 1):

Based off of this [Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/199088/highlight-console-output), I've created the following function:

```
# mylite since 'highlight' is already a program
function mylite () {
    pattern=$1; shift; file=$1
    grep -E --color "$pattern|$" $file
}
```

Usage examples:

```
mylite pattern file.txt
cat file.txt | mylite pattern
```

No beeping in this example, but I'm sure that can be added by modifying `grep` as shown by other answers on this page.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake on the answer.  I tried this:

```
PATTERN="something"
export GREP_COLOR='1;37;41' # set to a sequence of xterm escape sequences for colorization.
export GREP_OPTIONS=--color=always

while read LINE
do
    echo $LINE | grep $PATTERN || echo $LINE
done
```

Comment: But grep will only show the lines that match, right? I want to see all of the output with the matching lines highlighted.

Comment: To ring the bell on each match: `echo $LINE | grep $PATTERN && echo -n $'\07' || echo $LINE`. However spawning `grep` for each line could be expensive.

Comment: To see all the output with the matching lines highlighted, use `grep -C999 $PATTERN`.  That assumes that there are no more than 2 * 999 lines between matches.  If you want the whole line containing the match highlighted, use `grep -C999 ".*$PATTERN.*"`.

Comment: Rather than spawning a `grep` for each line, you could use `sed` to insert a bell on each colored line, like this: `grep -C999 --color=always $PATTERN | sed '/^[/s/^/^G/'`. The `^[` is a literal Esc and `^G` is a literal BEL, or Ctrl-G. Those characters can be entered into the `sed` command by typing Ctrl-V before each one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like [logwatch](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logwatch/files/) may be what you are looking for.