# Highlight console search output, while displaying entire command output

Tags: linux, command-line

When I use e.g. `cat file.txt | grep --color=tty "pattern"` I get the pattern I search highlighted. When I want some more context around each hit, grep has the `-A`, `-B` and `-C` parameters.

However, I want to display the whole file (or whatever command output) and highlight a certain pattern. Does such a highlight command or tool exist?

Comment: How is what you want to do now different from what you already do?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There was an [answer on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366/convince-grep-to-output-all-lines-not-just-those-with-matches/367#367) that had this neat trick:

```
grep -E --color 'pattern|$' file.txt
```

or

```
grep --color 'pattern\|$' file.txt
```

which matches your pattern or the end-of-line on each line. Only the pattern is highlighted.

Comment: +1 Simple, and easily adaptable to zgrep, bzgrep, etc. Nice!

Comment: Is there any way to avoid typing --color all the time? I think its pretty basic to embed color option into grep, not sure why we have explicitly type in color every single time. I tried to create scripts say grepd files has a bash saying grep --color $1 $2 but it doesnt work. Any clue here to fix this please

Comment: @lordlupine: Add `GREP_OPTIONS='--color'` to your `~/.bashrc` (or modify the setting to include `--color`). You will need to start a new terminal or execute that assignment at the command line in the current terminal to have it take effect.

Answer (score 10):

I like [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/).

```
ack --passthru somepattern filename
```

It's like grep, but better. It highlights by default, and with the `--passthru` option it shows the entire file (or standard input) instead of only the matching lines.

Comment: If you're trying to pipe output into ack, e.g. from `tail`, then you need to use the `--filter` option too.
For example:
`tail -f myLogFile | ack --filter --passthru pattern`

Comment: @sparrowt Can you please explain briefly why it's necessary? (e.g. any fringe cases where not using `--filter` would cause a problem?) I used it w/o `--filter` and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm afraid my memory from 7 years ago is patchy!  At the time I found that (in my environment: OS, shell, version of tail/ack, etc.) `--filter` was required to "Force ack to treat standard input as a pipe" per the ack documentation. I'm not sure why it was necessary, or whether something has been fixed since then - so if it works without that's great, but if someone finds it doesn't work then try adding `--filter`! :)

Answer (score 6):

I also recommend the use of `less` (or such), but I want to show you a more didactical solution. Once you have defined this function:

```
function highlight()
{
    sed "s/$1/`tput smso`&`tput rmso`/g" "${2:--}"
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
command | highlight pattern
highlight pattern file.txt
```

**Note:** This version is case sensitive, to change that just append `i` after `g` in the `sed` expression.

Comment: I'd invoke `tput` instead of hardcoding the values. This way you also avoid using `echo -e`, which can have other effects.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I searched it with no luck. Thanks.

Comment: This version doesn't need the capturing parentheses and can be run either by `prog | highlight "pattern"` or `highlight "pattern" file`: `highlight () { local file=${2:--}; sed "s/$1/$(tput smso)&$(tput rmso)/gi" "$file"; }`

Comment: My `sed` skills are basically not existent. How would I have to change that in order to match the pattern case sensitive. Anyway, I will add that one to my bash_functions include. Thank you very much.

Comment: @DerMike: Now it's case sensitive.

Answer (score 3):

`less` is highlighting pattern, so

```
less -p 'mypattern' file.txt
```

or

```
ridiculously | long | pipe | less
```

and then in less `/` to search for a pattern which will be highlighted.

Side note:

You can improve your command, for example
set alias `alias grep="grep --color=tty"` and use it like that:

```
grep 'mypattern' file.txt;
```

Comment: you should refrain from using GREP_OPTIONS, use alias instead. see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/67141

Comment: Primum non nocere. removed.

Comment: GREP_OPTIONS is used by many forms of `grep` (zgrep, bzgrep, bzfgrep, etc.) So, if you want all forms of grep to behave consistently, you'd need to set an alias for each form of grep. @Casual's new answer above won't for with something like `bzgrep pattern /var/log/messages.?.gz`, which is an example where color highlighting be VERY helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Passing `-C` to `grep` with a sufficiently high value will do this.

Comment: I Could have sworn I got some thing else last time I tried that. (Each match the context with '-----' separators in between.) Now that you told me, it runs fine :-) Thank you.

Comment: It will separate each match, if there isn't enough context.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice [supercat](http://supercat.nosredna.net) tool, which serves exactly that purpose. It can both colorize your console output and produce a "highlighted" html from your input.

Comment: Thanks, that looks promissing. However, I can't seem to get it working at the moment.

Comment: Take a look at its config files (in `/etc/supercat` on Ubuntu), which set up the coloring rules, they are basically color/regexp pairs (with some extra rules); man page is also short and nice.

Comment: I found a `spcrc` vim syntax file at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2676