# Highlight selected words in Linux Command Usage Doc

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, grep

What I want to do is print a command-help (viz. "ls --help") and grep the output for any specific word. Consider the following:

`ls --help | grep 'F'`

But what this does is just filter out the other useful help.

I am aware of -A, -B, -C options for grep, but I want a better solution.

[Highlight console search output, while displaying entire command output](https://superuser.com/questions/199088/highlight-console-search-output-while-displaying-entire-command-output)

This link gives the basic usage of the command, but I want to have something like:

`grep -E --color 'pattern' <<<SOME COMMAND HERE>>>`

E.G: `grep -E --color 'pattern' <ls --help>`

Is it possible to do? Basically, grep the `ls --help` but also print the whole help doc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer,

You can use Extended Grep like:

`ls --help | egrep '<pattern>|'`

Like- `ls --help | egrep 'F|'`

Notice the pipe at the end. Alternately, you can use `grep -E`

This answer was originally posted at: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28210153/2095777